# What is the adjectival form for the noun ‘accismus’? Is it ‘accismatic’?

Tags: single-word-requests, adjectives

I've been looking for a word in English that expresses the following meaning:

The state of wanting something but feigning disinterest  because you want the other party to insist,  ask more forcefully/affectionately, etc.

So far, the best word I've found is *accismus*. Now I'm wondering if it also has an adjective I can use. Unfortunately, dictionaries haven't been of much help. If there is no such word, do you think *accismatic* can be a welcome addition to English vocabulary?

Comment: **Accismus** is pretty high-register. In colloquial speech you might want to go with something like _playing hard to get._

Comment: What is the context where you want to use this? If you're addressing readers who will be familiar with the terminology of classical rhetoric, they'll probably understand, if you get the word form right (I don't know enough Latin to tell you if -atic is the right suffix to use there). Anyone else is going to be scratching their heads, and you could make up whatever word you wanted, they'll rely on you providing context or a glossary anyway.

Comment: This has resurfaced, SEZ. Hello. 'Do you think _accismatic_ [could] be a welcome addition to English vocabulary?' I've a pretty reasonable vocabulary (including rhetorical terms), but had to check on _accismus_.  User405662 is using understatement. You could introduce 'accismatic' in clarifying context with scare-quotes as a nonce-word to a suitable audience if you find it useful, but that doesn't convey 'wordness'. A more general acceptance (which _accismus_ has achieved; it's in several respected dictionaries) is required. One person _can_ invent words (eg 'hobbit', 'quidditch'). But rarely.

Answer (score 1):

You are looking for a single word. This requires that you give an example sentence that clearly shows how you wish to use it.

In the meantime, **dissimulate -> dissimulated** is not exact but it is close:

OED

> **2.a. To conceal or disguise under a feigned appearance; to dissemble.**
>
> 1882   R. L. Stevenson New Arabian Nights I. 193   *If ever..he described some experience personal to himself, it was so aptly dissimulated as to pass unnoticed with the rest.*

As far as the etymology is concerned:

> accismus, n. Etymology: < post-classical Latin accismus (1528 in Erasmus) < Hellenistic Greek ἀκκισμός coyness, affectation < ancient Greek ἀκκίζεσθαι to affect indifference, to affect ignorance, dissemble, to affect to be shocked, to be coy

Answer (score -1):

I would say that's appropriate from what I see, and there's no adjective for the term. It was the first thing I thought of. I'm not sure if the term is coined, but I doubt anyone would correct you in conversation.

Comment: It would help if you offered some evidence, either examples of authors using the word, or at least explaining how comparable words form adjectives, e.g. *strabismus* gives *strabismal* or *strabismic*.